# Using AWS SDK on .net with localstack (TransferUtility/S3 - setting endpoint)

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, localstack

I have localstack (https://github.com/localstack/localstack) running and am able to use the aws s3 cli to upload files to it.

What I want to be able to do is use the .NET AWS ADK with localstack. I'd like the following code to upload a file into localstack:

```
        using (var tfu = new TransferUtility())
        {
            await tfu.UploadAsync(new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {
                Key = key,
                BucketName = bucketName,
                ContentType = document.ContentType,
                Headers = { ["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"test.txt\"" },
                InputStream = stream
            });
        }
```

My problem is I don't know how to set the endpoints so that localstack is used by the SDK rather than aws. Apparently you can set the `AWSEndpointDefinition` in appSettings.config as mentioned in the AWS SDK documentation, e.g:

`<add key="AWSEndpointDefinition" value="C:\Dev\localstack\endpoints.json"/>`

However I have no idea what this endpoints.json config should look like. I tried using this file:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/master/sdk/src/Core/endpoints.json

When I do this, as soon as I new up a `TransferUtility` class I get a null reference exception - this is before I point anything to my localstack setup.

The version of AWS ASK is 3.3.0.

Another thing to note is that in some places in the documentation it is implied that the config should be an xml file rather than a json, however, when I try to use an xml file instead I get a different exception when newing up `TransferUtility`: 'Invalid character '<' in input string'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily override it by creating an S3 client and passing it to TransferUtility constructor.

```
var config = new AmazonS3Config { ServiceURL = "http://localhost:4572" };
var s3client = new AmazonS3Client(config);
```

Do not forget to replace URL if your localstack is using different port for S3.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but for anyone still looking for a solution or end up in this thread, I'd like to introduce a tool that might help.

I maintain a project called [LocalStack.NET](https://github.com/localstack-dotnet/localstack-dotnet-client), which is a thin wrapper around the AWS SDK.NET. It's designed to automatically configure the target endpoints to use LocalStack, making it easier to integrate .NET applications with LocalStack.

With LocalStack.NET, you don't need to set endpoint configurations manually. The library takes care of it for you. Here's a simple example of how you can use it:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddLocalStack(Configuration)
    services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
    services.AddAwsService<IAmazonS3>();
}
```

This automatically sets the endpoint to LocalStack's default for S3. The library supports other AWS services provided by LocalStack as well.

For a more detailed guide on how to get started with LocalStack.NET, you can take a look at the [Getting Started documentation](https://github.com/localstack-dotnet/localstack-dotnet-client/wiki/Getting-Started).

Additionally, I've recently prepared [a demo application](https://github.com/localstack-dotnet/localstack-serverless-dotnet-demo) showcasing serverless architecture using .NET, AWS, and LocalStack. It might provide further insights into integrating .NET with LocalStack.

I hope this helps future readers and anyone looking to integrate .NET with LocalStack.