# AWS S3 Bucket Access when connecting to Lumen

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core

I am trying to connect to a client's S3 bucket. I am getting the error "The AWS Access Key you provided does not exist in our records".

Using Postman, I can connect using the Access Key ID, Key Secret and the bucket endpoint provided by the client. I can perform all the operations I need to (in this case, overwrite a JSON file in the bucket).

I wish to write some C# that will do the same.

```
var jsonObject = listOfStrings;
var jsonBytes = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(jsonObject);
await using var stream = new MemoryStream(jsonBytes);

var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(_lumenServiceConfiguration.KeyId,
            _lumenServiceConfiguration.KeySecret,
            RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);

var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
await transferUtility.UploadAsync(stream, _lumenServiceConfiguration.Endpoint, "file.json").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The config options are set to what the client has specified i.e. all the same details I have used in Postman.

The client said "it's not in AWS, it's our own storage platform". Exactly what that means, I am not 100% and I cannot get them to clarify further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your client's comments, it would appear that they are not actually using AWS. Instead, they are using an "S3-Compatible" service such as [Eucalyptus](https://www.eucalyptus.cloud/). In fact, given your code, it would seem that they are using [Lumen Network Storage Object Tier](https://www.lumen.com/help/en-us/network-storage/creating-an-object-tier-bucket-using-an-s3-browser.html).

They have likely provided you with an "Endpoint", which is a URL where requests should be sent.

Based on the answer to [Using AWS SDK on .net with localstack (TransferUtility/S3 - setting endpoint)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50971824/174777), you should provide the Endpoint when constructing the `AmazonS3Client`, such as:

```
var config = new AmazonS3Config { ServiceURL = "http://localhost:4572" };
var s3client = new AmazonS3Client(config);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, John! That has worked a treat. 

Just an FYI for anyone else that comes across this issue, don't add the additional line to the config...

`var config = new AmazonS3Config
            {
                ServiceURL = _lumenServiceConfiguration.Endpoint,
                RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest2
            };`

This gave me the following error...

"The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint."

So, using John's answer, as provided is the full solution.